# IE compatible outer input referring form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

### Situation

I have a form

```
<form action="." method="POST" id="my_form">
    <!-- Form stuff here -->
</form>
<p onclick="confirmUpdate();">Update</p>
```

The `confirmUpdate()` function generates a confirmation message and the following input tag:

```
<input type="submit" name="my_name" value="Yes. Update the data.">
```

using the following JavaScript:

```
inputYes.type = 'submit';
inputYes.name = 'my_name';
inputYes.value = 'Yes. Update the data.';
inputYes.form = 'my_form';
```

The page is created as intended, but the input element has no `form="my_form"` on it.

### Condition

The HTML generated with Javascript has to be shown as a nice "HTML pop-up" (not an alert box) to ask the user if the info is correct before submitting.

### Questions

1. Why isn't it working?
2. The JavaScript generated HTML doesn't appear on the Page Source. Will it be able to submit the data from the form?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is inputYes?  Can you post the relevant javascript code and/or create a jsFiddle?

Comment: @RickS Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andradei/B7QAc/2/) for it. Thank you for suggesting this tool.

Comment: You want the "Yes. Update the Data" button to submit the form?  Is that the part that isn't working?

Comment: @RickS Precisely. The form attribute is not being added to the input tag that has the `value="Yes. Update the Data.`

Comment: Check my amswer below. Should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) instead:

```
inputYes.setAttribute('form', 'my_form');
```

Comment: I know there are issues with setAttribute in IE8, which is what I am developing for, is there another way?

Comment: @sargas looks like IE8 is supported http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536739(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get your input button to work, then inside your method confirmUpdate(), make the following additions/changes:

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/B7QAc/4/

```
//add this 
var theform = document.getElementById('my_form');

//change this
document.body.appendChild(screenDiv);

//to this
theform.appendChild(screenDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answers were correct, I found a better solution for my problem. I had to update the question in order to make it more clear. The HTML generated with Javascript was intended to show as a nice "pop-up" to ask the user if the info is correct before submitting.

Therefore, the `<input>` tag has to be outside of the `<form>` and reference its `id="my_form"` via a `form="my_form` attribute.

### Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andradei/B7QAc/7/) for it.

While `inputYes.form = 'my_form';` doesn't add the `form` attribute, `inputYes.setAttribute('form', 'my_form');` does the job.

**Notice** though that it only works at the end of the script, **only** after it is appended to the HTML Document. It would not work otherwise (at least in this script).

Even though I lack the technical knowledge to explain it better, those are my observations.

This would be the accepted answer. I will promptly accept any other answer that is more complete than this one.